# Failed to import media from a local wordpress site to a live one

Tags: media, import

I've been developing a new blog theme for a client locally on my computer and am now in the process of uploading this to the new live server. I used the wordpress export facility to export all the content from the local site and then went into the live installation and used the import facility - I checked the boxed the referred to file attachments - but no media gets imported onto the live blog. I've got about 255 posts and don't fancy having to go in and set the featured image manually for each and every post.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way I can upload all the media easily?

Comment: no response as yet. need to get this blog sorted asap so I'm going to try out this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/ and try and import all my media that way and then just go through every published post and manually add the featured image to each... a pain in the derier but it's the only way I can see me getting the work done asap.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in import mechanism can only fetch file attachments that are accessible over the internet - which will normally not apply to your local WP install.
The best option is to dump the whole database and do an MySQL import on the receiving domain. Your image files and other attachments need to be ftp-ed to the production server. However, your local and server configurations must be the same for this to work without additional measures. Better try this route some other time.
Good luck!

Comment: thanks - I've managed to get it all done using the add from server plugin - although it was a bit time consuming. I wouldn't normally have this issue as I normally work on totally new sites and so don't need to worry about it. But with this project I've been dealing with three years worth of blogging and new functioanlity and a new theme etc, so had to take the long winded approach as I developed the new blog locally on my PC - if I have to do this again, I'm going to work on my live dev server as then I should be able to export and import media.